# Setting an environment value in swift causes unrelated view to redraw when importing unrelated environment value

Tags: swiftui

I'm experiencing some strange behaviour in a SwiftUI app and I was wondering if it could be explained somehow. As the title says, when updating an environment value in my view hierarchy, it causes a redraw of a child view in my hierarchy when that child uses *any* environment value at all (at least all of the ones I've tested).

I can't provide a simple example that works, but I also can't think of what could even cause this issue:

This is the basic idea

```
struct RootView: View {
  @State let manager = ManagerItem.default
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      ...
         ... // this could be a deep hierarchy with a childview somewhere along the way
         ChildView()
         ...
      ...
      Button {
        // change manager item here for example
      }
    }
    .environment(\.managerItem, manager) // manager is a struct if that matters
  }
}

struct ChildView: View {
   // If I add any @Environment declarations in this view, the background color
   // will change when the managerItem environment value changes above
   // If I omit all @Environment declarations from this view
   // the view will *not* redraw when the managerItem environment value changes above
   @Environment(\.colorScheme) private var colorScheme
   // Example 2
   @Environment(\.someCustom) private var someCustom
   // Example 3
   @Environment(\.multilineTextAlignment) private var multilineTextAlignment

   var body: some View {
     Rectangle().fill(Color.random) // Extension that generates a random color
   }
}
```

This is a shot in the dark, I'm unable to reproduce this is a simple application, but to me this shouldn't be happening. I cant find anywhere in the app where any of the `@Environment` values in ChildView are changed.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: In your real app, does `ChildView` take any parameters, like maybe a closure?

Comment: Also, try adding [`let _ = Self._printChanges()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift-playgrounds/console-print-debugging#Understand-when-and-why-your-views-change) in the `body` of `ChildView` to see why SwiftUI thinks it needs to be re-evaluated.